# Override Alfresco Login

Tags: java, spring, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise

I'm trying to Override Alfresco 5.0d Login using java class I tried a lot of things and I understand how does it work but I'm stuck.

**my work is to add a policy that if a user tries to log in 3 times and fail I will disable the user account and send an email to that user telling him that someone is trying to connect to your account**

so I added a class called CustomLogin that Extends AbstractAuthenticationComponent and I also added the 
    `authentication.chain=alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm,CustomLoginController:CustomLoginController` to **alfresco-global-properties**

and when I deploy that AMP I get an Error message in alfresco.log telling me that

> specified for Authentication subsystem. No context file found

- alfresco SDK 2.2
- JDK 7
- alfresco 5.0d

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**authentication.chain** is used for external authentication.For example if you would like to use Active Directory then you can use this configuration to add user of active directory.

If you would like to implement this than i think you need to override LoginController which is defined inside slingshot-application-context.xml file.

For disabling the user you need to add **cm:personDisabled** aspect in a cm:person object.

Refer below link for how user is defined in alfresco.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Alfresco/community-edition-old/master/projects/repository/config/alfresco/model/contentModel.xml

SlingshotLoginController.java is controller class which you need to override.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your `CustomLoginController:CustomLoginController` using Bean configuration.

The bean configuration may not available so that this exception is coming

> `specified for Authentication subsystem. No context file found`

Please refer the [documentation](http://specified%20for%20Authentication%20subsystem.%20No%20context%20file%20found) for more detail.